# Get Last N Element From Entity by LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

I want to find the last primary id of a table. Table Name: table1
columns: Id, name, age

```
var id = _db.table1.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().Id
```

The above query is causing performance problem when records exceed 100 000 records. How to improve the performance?

Comment: use `.Max(x => x.Id).Id` instead?

Comment: I hope you do not retrieve the last Id to create a new one. Setting an Index on your db table can help.

Comment: Try this. 0 will be returned if no records from db .  var id = _db.table1.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => x == null ? 0 : x.Id).Id;

Comment: What is type of _db.table1?

Comment: @anand why do you need to fetch the last primary Id of the table? We can come up with the best solution based on your requirement.

Comment: Use `LastOrDefault()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` without using `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Don't construct primary keys yourself.  Let the database set the key.  It will both be faster and will be reliably correct, unlike it would be if you tried to do it in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under assumption that _db.Table1 is queryable you can try following:

```
var id = _db.table1.Max(e => e.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue you could issue a raw query against the database:

```
int id = _db.table1.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT MAX([Id]) FROM dbo.table1").FirstOrDefault<int>();
```

**Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

It doesn't get any faster than this as far as the selection of data is concerned.